# Why limit request variable name and value lengths

Tags: http

I have a server with suhosin installed (a protection system for PHP installations). I noticed software I am running is causing the following logs on suhosin.

```
ALERT - configured GET variable value length limit exceeded - dropped variable
ALERT - configured request variable name length limit exceeded - dropped variable
```

Could allowing long request variable names or values present a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excessively long parameters often play a role in overflow vulnerabilities or denial of service attacks.  If you increase the `max_value_length` or `max_varname_length` values you don't create an immediate threat but might facilitate these attacks in the future.

A related example: In 2011, the [HashDoS attack](http://www.slideshare.net/stamparm/hash-dos-attack) against PHP became public. The idea was to supply a high amount of specially crafted POST parameters which intentionally caused hash table collisions, consuming an excessive amount of system resources that eventually led to a denial of service. Back then, a Suhosin configuration with a low value for `suhosin.post.max_vars` would have mitigated this attack. Although this example is about a high amount of parameters and not long individual parameter values, these could lead to similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes.

To elaborate, by limiting the size of variables, you reduce the chances that an attack will be successful.  This is because the limit reduces the chance that the information passed can trigger an overflow, the chance that the variable will be able to hold an effective payload, and the chance that the system can be overwhelmed when processing overlong variables.

If it's a legitimately long variable, you should be possible to increase the limit, but keep in mind the larger the limit, the greater the amount of space potential attackers will have to play with.